# Random Forest not predicting zeros

Tags: python, random-forest, prediction, missing-data, zero

I'm running a random forest on a data-set which contains a lot of zeros. These zeros represent a count of something (or absence thereof) and therefore are meaningful, by contrast to data that could be classed as 'missing'.

When I run the predictions I am finding that my RF seems to be reluctant to predict zero, almost like it is not viewing 0 as a number and so defaults to 1 instead. Is there a way I can address this? I just find it odd that zero is not appearing as a prediction at any time.

Comment: Please provide a [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Answer (score 0):

This is not very surprising to me but it really depends on your dataset. 
Basically, random forests outputs are averages of the training values (if you don't know how it is computed, I invite you to look for some theory that will help you understand how a random forest is calculated...). So except if your target is almost exclusively compounded of zeros or extremely well defined patterns (e.g. if a certain feature takes some specific value(s), then the target is **always** 0) representing a lot of training cases, the odds for getting exactly 0 as an output are very low.

That being said, if your output is expected to be an integer (for instance 0), you might round it.